# CSS Modules for components vs pages in react/nextjs - will it run properly if the modules are for components instead of for pages when deployed?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm building my first NextJS app and am having trouble adjusting to CSS modules. When I've used create-react-app to build my react apps, I'll use sass and I have one style component for each react component. With CSS modules, can I do the same thing? Like, create a SCSS module for a component and import it as styles into the correct component? Or do I need to make a SCSS module for each page?

Currently, my app is working the way I've asked, I just want to make sure that it'll still work when deployed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.